# Why Doesn't Set-CASMailbox Remove Mobile Device from Exchange 2019 Quarantine?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2019

I am writing a script to remove devices from quarantine but even though the code seems to "work" it does not ever actually remove the device from quarantine.

I am running this code

```
Set-CASMailbox -Identity $username -ActiveSyncAllowedDeviceIDs @{add="$mobileDevices[[int]$menuSelect].DeviceID"} -Confirm:$True
```

The first time it gives no return output just a new prompt.  If I run it again it now says:

```
WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'chry/Domain Sites/Cedar/Canon Lan' have been modified.
```

So it seems that it successfully added the allowed device ID but when I run Get-MobileDevice it still shows Device Access State: Quarantined and it also still shows in the GUI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have not been able to find anything searching so far.

Comment: Do you need active sync such as `ActiveSyncMailboxPolicy` ?

Comment: Looks like [ad replication](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Exchange/Quarantined-Mobile-Devices-Powershell/td-p/202831) might need to occur?

Comment: Or just [remove-mobiledevice](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/unblock-mobile-device-exchange-server/)

Comment: Hey Lloyd not sure what you mean by your first question but the second I have everything set like the link at ad replication and for Remove-MobileDevice wouldn't that remove its access to email?